# Change in Gradle/Manifest messed up the whole app

Tags: android

My app was due for release this past weekend, and everything worked as intended. The app ran perfectly on 3 phones, all running API 14+. First, I will show how the app looked pre-release:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-H3L0fyEmZT28wNzlJS1RKeG8/edit?usp=sharing

Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 'android-L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

And in the manifest,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
```

Was able to be put under the -application- tag, instead of under the direct manifest. It still ran just fine. Putting this instead under the main -manifest- caused an error, removing it completely also caused an error, so we left it in . Weird.

---

After researching for hours, I changed the gradle files to the following

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
```

and moved the uses-sdk section into the manifest. It ran, but it was NOTHING like it should look.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-H3L0fyEmZWWIwOEFfVjNkaDA/edit?usp=sharing

I am currently using AppCompat Light as the theme.
I've spend 10 hours+ trying to figure this magic out, but nothing! What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-sdk />` is meaningless in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you're using Gradle. It'll be entirely* ignored. The problem is that you cannot release an app targeting android-L at this point -- it's built specifically to prevent that at this point.

* It can be useful in some cases for resolving conflicts, but the values are ignored.

Comment: I understand that it cannot be released as L, and I noted that I changed that. I also know that uses-sdk can be ignored, but there is no reason to just remove it. This doesn't doesn't explain why everything looks so extremely different simply from changing the sdk values.

Comment: It does, though. The material themes only apply when targeting android-L. I'm fairly certain (although I might be wrong) that API 20 targets 4.4 (Android Wear) whereas `android-L` is specific to the L preview.